Is it necessary to use fflush more than once?
In APUE (Advanced programming in UNIX environment), there are a lots of err_quit, err_sys and like them.
The source of for example err_quit is as follows:
void err_quit(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list     ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    err_doit(0, 0, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    exit(1);
}

static void err_doit(int errnoflag, int error, const char *fmt, va_list ap) {
    char    buf[MAXLINE];

    vsnprintf(buf, MAXLINE-1, fmt, ap);
    if (errnoflag)
        snprintf(buf+strlen(buf), MAXLINE-strlen(buf)-1, ": %s",
          strerror(error));
    strcat(buf, "\n");
    fflush(stdout);     /* in case stdout and stderr are the same */  /* LINE A*/
    fputs(buf, stderr);
    fflush(NULL);       /* flushes all stdio output streams */        /* LINE B*/
}

My question is LINE A necessary, because of existence of LINE B ?  I can not understand the comments inLINE A.

Your only write to stderr with fputs (buf, "\n"); (which in itself an incorrect use of  int fputs(const char *s, FILE *stream); ) "\n" does not constitute a FILE *stream object. Now step back and ask "Why do I think I need to fflush(stdout);?  stdout is line-buffered by default so any time your output includes a '\n' character, that line will be written to stdout without having to call fflush(stdout);. Now if you just fputs ("xxxx", stdout); where no '\n' is at the end of "xxxx" - then you will need fflush(stdout); to force "xxxx" out of the buffer early.

@DavidC.Rankin I don't see fputs (buf, "\n") anywhere in the OP's code, which in fact is W. Rich Stevens' code.

See Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string? for a more thorough discussion on the subject. @user207421 my bad it was fputs (buf, stderr); -- getting senile...

The idea is to flush stdout before stderr, so that you don't get their pending outputs overlapped. So 'more than once' doesn't actually apply.

@DavidC.Rankin: stdout is not “line-buffered by default.” It depends on what it is connected to. So, to get the desired behavior in all cases, one may use fflush as user207421 notes above.

So long as you are not redirecting it, it is line-buffered.

@DavidC.Rankin: Re “So long as you are not redirecting it, it is line-buffered.” So? That means there are situations where stdout is not line-buffered, so getting the desired behavior requires using fflush.

I'm sorry, I failed to see any applicable corner-case in the Question. What text are you relying on there?

@DavidC.Rankin The point is that this is very defensive code, that does not assume that stderr and stdout are different, or that stdout has not been redirected.

@DavidC.Rankin: What corner case? It is a plain main case. If you direct both standard output and standard error to the same pipe or file, they are fully buffered, and the output can become interleaved. As the program writes to stdout, some of it will be sent to the pipe or file when the buffer is full, and then part of it will be held in the buffer. Then, when the program writes to stderr, that can be sent to the pipe or file while there is still pending data in the stdout buffer, so you can fragments of messages from one stream interwoven with data from the other. Flushing avoids that.

@tahzibi.jafar, Aside: rather than strlen(), strcat(), use the return value from vsnprintf() (if not negative) to quickly determine the buffer length.

@tahzibi.jafar, Comment in fflush(NULL);       /* flushes all stdio output streams */  is amiss.  fflush(NULL); flushes all output streams, not only all stdio output streams. This includes output streams associated with files, etc.  So better as fflush(NULL); /* flush all output streams */ .

This program apparently prints to both stdout and stderr. On Linux, the standard error stream is unbuffered by default. When the standard output stream is connected a pipe or file, it is fully buffered by default, and then the output to these streams can become mixed. Unbuffered means the stream software sends output to the device as soon as the program writes it. Fully buffered means the stream software does not immediately send output to the device but instead records it internally in a buffer and sends it to the device only when the buffer is full or a flush is requested. This is done for efficiency, because it reduces the number of system calls and I/O operations needed to process the output. Each buffered stream has a separate buffer.
For example, suppose the program wrote some text to stdout before this routine err_doit was called, perhaps the text Continuing program operations, everything is good.\n, and then err_doit is called and writes Error, the deaggregating fluxinator reported a zizzification error.\n to both stderr. What can happen with no fflush calls is:

When the first message was written to stdout, Continuing program operations, filled the buffer, so the stream software sent the full buffer to the pipe or file.
Then the stream software put the rest of the text,  everything is good.\n into the buffer.
err_doit was called and wrote Error, the deaggregating fluxinator reported a zizzification error.\n to stderr. Since standard error is unbuffered, this was sent immediately.
When the program is terminating, the buffers are flushed. When stdout is flushed,  everything is good.\n is sent to the pipe or file.

The result is the pipe or file receives this text:
Continuing program operations,Error, the deaggregating fluxinator reported a zizzification error.
 everything is good.

So the user ends up seeing chopped and mixed messages in the pipe or file. That is not what we want. To avoid that, the program flushes stdout before it writes to stderr. This ensures the pipe or file will receive:
Continuing program operations, everything is good.
Error, the deaggregating fluxinator reported a zizzification error.

You usually will not see this when you run a program at the command line and let the standard output and standard error connect to the terminal. This is because, when standard output is connected to a terminal, the default is that it is line buffered, meaning the program will record output internally and only send it to the device when the buffer is full, a new-line character is written, or a flush is requested. So, whenever the program writes a line containing a new-line character, the output up to that character is immediately sent to the terminal. That prevents interweaving of stdout and stderr data as long as the program ends each output with a new-line character.
That explains the first fflush(stdout);. The reason for the later fflush(NULL); (which requests flushing of all streams with possibly pending output) is not clear. It will flush the standard error stream if it is buffered, but that may or may not be the author’s intent.
